# How to make carousel and scrolling animation work together on single web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have single web page, and I use scroll animation function to move between sections which is this one

```
$(function() {

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 2000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

It is all working fine, when I click on my menu let's say contact link scroll animation do it's job and smoothly takes me to contact section. Then I add carousel for sliding images, this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#media').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false,
  });
});
```

but it wont work as long as scrolling function is in my js file, when I remove scroll animation function my carousel work just fine. Is there a way to make them work together? Any help would be appreciated.

And here is HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Media Slider Carousel BS3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                <p>sportska masaža</p>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if ur interested to use plugin u can reffer https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: I never use plugins before, please can you explane what I need to do next to solve my problem

Comment: Which `carousel` are you using? Can you create a working demo? (Use the `<>` button from the editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a condition, that your carousel links are not effected from your scroll function:

```
if($(this).parents('#media').length == 0)
```

Let's have a look:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).parents('#media').length == 0) {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 2000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $('#media').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Media Slider Carousel BS3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item  active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                <p>sportska masaža</p>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>          
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
              </div>      
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
      </div>                          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, with this condition, can you explane me to logic behind it, what is condition testing in this example, btw tnx a lot!!! :)

Comment: this condition checks if your clicked link has a parent element with the id `media` and you have media only defined in your carousel. so if you have media as parent, it will do nothing. without this condition your carousel action will be interrupted by your function.